# Structured references vs explicit cell references

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using Index-Match to match Full Names with head count in that party.
I have it working but it uses both the structured and explicit cell reference.
I can't figure out why when I add a new row in my table, the column with the index-match formula wont populate the last row.

This is the formula used:

```
=IFNA(INDEX(AA:AA,MATCH([@[Preferred Seating 1st Choice]],D:D,0)),"")
```

Column AA has the head count number and column D has the list of full names. 
Preferred Seating is the column used to reference the search.

I looked around and can't seem to find why it wont fill in the last row after that rown info is entered.
I can only assume it has something to do with the mixed Explicit-structured cell/column references. Any help please.
[image]
[image]

Comment: BTW all other formulas carry down nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Excel may not automatically assume a formula needs to be automatically filled in an entire table column if it contains unusual references. Unless you have data outside the table, you should just refer to the columns in the table:

```
=IFNA(INDEX([Column AA Name],MATCH([@[Preferred Seating 1st Choice]],[Column D Name],0)),"")
```

These can be easily entered when editing the formula by selecting all cells in the source columns excluding the heading. The formula will always use the entire 
source columns and the formula should automatically fill its own entire column.

You can also control whether a column automatically has its formula updated through a hidden property. The ability to change the behavior of the column only appears through the front end when you're making changes to the column.

After entering a formula in a column, Excel will either automatically fill the entire column and give you the option to turn off the automatic fill, or Excel will not automatically fill the entire column and give you the option to turn it on.

After entering a formula that isn't being filled, this icon will appear:

[image]

Click it and then select to Overwrite all cells in this column with this formula

[image]

Deleting a formula from one cell in a column that is being automatically filled will turn off the automatic fill. Double clicking a cell with a formula and pressing enter will give you the option to turn it on again.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.As I have attempted many troubleshooting methods, I am still unable to have it fill down to the last row.

Comment: I Verified all the checkboxes in the option settings are checked for this option.

Comment: I am still unable to make this work. I have 4 columns with the Index-Match function that have the same issue. After a new entry in a row, those 4 columns wont fill in. Upon checking those cells, they are blank. I tried everything I can think of and did the above modification but with no luck. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I dont know what checkboxes you're talking about. Do you get the popup i showed when entering a formula?

Comment: Yes I do and that's been working fine. Te reason I was asking if it was a index match thing is because I have numerous other columns with other than index match formulas, and they are autofilling to the newest role but the 4 columns with index match are not.

Comment: I added a picture about the checkboxes I was talking about

Comment: So for those columns with the index match formulas, do you get any kind of popup when you enter a formula? And did you try changing the formula as I suggested to refer to table columns instead of entire worksheet columns?

Comment: Yes I was always getting the popup.

Comment: Yes I deleted the formula and done it again to no avail

Comment: I'm down to guessing something is corrupted in the workbook... if you recreate that formula in a new table in a new workbook, do you get the same issue? I have no other suggestions sorry.

Comment: Yup...there must be some corruption somewhere.